# How to pass one JavaBean object as DataSource

Tags: jasper-reports

Exists there a way to pass one javaBean object as a datasource of my jasperReport without using `JRBeanCollectionDataSource` which requires a collection of javaBeans as parameter ?

Comment: You can use parameters for passing data and Title band for showing data

Comment: Ain't there any alternative solution where I can declare my javaBean attributes as fields in my report instead of parameters?

Comment: We get data at fields as result of using some datasource. You can look at all implementations of [JRDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRDataSource.html) interface to find the best for solving your task. Or you can implement your own datasource

Comment: Thank you Alex. I tried to look for some other solution, but I would rather stick with using report's parameters

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in using the `JRBeanCollectionDataSource` with just one item in a collection or the `JRBeanArrayDataSource` with one item in an array.

You can check out the [JasperReports Data Source Sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/datasource/index.html#datasources) and play with the data that is passed to each of them in the various fill methods.

Comment: Thank you for your reply